# AdMob For Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob, ads, windows-phone-8-emulator

i tried to add some ads to my apps, i downloaded the SDK and it's perfecly added
i wrote some code given in the admob website but it doesn't work , the emulator doesn't show anything ,

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <GoogleAds:AdView x:Name="bannerAD" Format="Banner"  AdUnitID="ca-app-pub-4074011335824507/6739534076" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="-1,542,-12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="469"/>

    </Grid>
```

can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

The following `ID_CAP` `capabilities` must be included in the `manifest` of the advertising-enabled app.

```
ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER
ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER
ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT
```

Your Height and Width should be according to the size you gave for the `banner` in the server.
For example if you've given there the size of `Width=480` & `Height=80` you should give the same size here.

Hope it helps :)